# Erro ao tentar renderizar componente com operador condicional ternário no REACT

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Esse é o meu componente

```
      {portaisAtuais
        .filter(portal => !portais.includes(portal.id))
        .map((portal, index) => {
          const { nome, id } = portal
          portaisAtuais.length === index + 1 ? ( 
            <div ref={ultimoPortal}>
              <GroupItem id={id} onClick={adicionarPortal} key={id}>
                {++index}- {nome}
                <Plus size="13" style={{ color: '#8BBA3F' }} />
              </GroupItem>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <GroupItem id={id} onClick={adicionarPortal}>
              {++index}- {nome}
              <Plus size="13" style={{ color: '#8BBA3F' }} />
            </GroupItem>
          )
        })}
```

Estou com problemas na renderização de acordo com os ternários da esse erro:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Fiz dar certo com if/else, mas preciso usar o operador condicional ternário ? :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa João, bom dia!

Você está esquecendo de retornar algo do `.map`. Seu código deve ficar dessa forma:

```
{portaisAtuais
    .filter(portal => !portais.includes(portal.id))
    .map((portal, index) => {
      const { nome, id } = portal
      return portaisAtuais.length === index + 1 ? ( 
        <div ref={ultimoPortal}>
          <GroupItem id={id} onClick={adicionarPortal} key={id}>
            {++index}- {nome}
            <Plus size="13" style={{ color: '#8BBA3F' }} />
          </GroupItem>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <GroupItem id={id} onClick={adicionarPortal}>
          {++index}- {nome}
          <Plus size="13" style={{ color: '#8BBA3F' }} />
        </GroupItem>
      )
    })}
```

Comment: Obrigado Luan, me ajudou muito cara! Errinho bobo kkk